# Haskell: Check if the first list is a prefix of the second

Tags: list, haskell, int, prefix

I am trying to write a program that checks if the first list is a prefix of the second list. for example, [5,6] is prefix of [1,5,6,7]. here is my working code but basically I don't have an idea on how to do it.

```
prefix [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool 
prefix [] [] = [] 
prefix y (x:xs)  
| x == y    = prefix y xs 
| otherwise = 0
```

any help please ?

Comment: `[5,6]` is *not* a prefix of `[1,5,6,7]`, `[1,5,6]` is. `[5,6]` is a *sublist* of `[1,5,6,7]`.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf

Answer (score 6):

Your code does not make much sense if we look at the types:

```
prefix [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool 
prefix [] [] = [] 
prefix y (x:xs)  
| x == y    = prefix y xs 
| otherwise = 0
```

Since the two arguments are lists (`[Int]`), this thus means that `y` is an `[Int]`, `x` is an `Int`, and `xs` is an `[Int]`. But then you compare `x == y`, you can not compare a list with an element. `(==)` is defined as `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`.

There are also other problems here: you return a list in the first clause, but the return type is a `Bool`, and later you return a `0` (again, it should be a `Bool`).

In case we define a function, we first need to define a certain model for it. When is a list *l1* a prefix of a list *l2*? In case *l1* is an empty list, then *l1* is always a prefix, regardless of the value of the second list, so:

```
prefix [] _ = True
```

In case *l1* is a list (i.e. `(x:xs)`), then it is *not* a prefix in two cases: (1) in case *l2* is an empty list; and (2) in case the first item of *l2* (`y` in `(y:ys))` is not equal to `x`, so:

```
prefix _ [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) | x /= y = False
                     | otherwise = ...
```

Now the question is what to do with `prefix (x:xs) (y:ys)` in case `x == y`. In that case we recurse on the two list, so the result of `prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) == prefix xs ys` (only in case `x == y`), so:

```
                     | otherwise = prefix xs ys
```

Or now in full:

```
prefix :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix _ [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) | x /= y = False
                     | otherwise = prefix xs ys
```

We can further generalize the expression to `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` such that it works with *any* type `a` that is an `Eq` instance (so there is a `(==)` instance defined over `a`):

```
prefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix _ [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) | x /= y = False
                     | otherwise = prefix xs ys
```

We can also swap the conditions, since usually *positive logic* is easier to understand than negative logic:

```
prefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix _ [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y = prefix xs ys
                     | otherwise = False
```

now we can furthermore remove the guards, and use an `(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` instead:

```
prefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix _ [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && prefix xs ys
```

Comment: @CommuSoft Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Just leaving my two cents here with a combination of functions from Prelude:

```hs
isPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPrefix l1 l2 = take (length l1) l2 == l1
```

Comment: I can't find `isPrefix` in Prelude, but `Data.List` does have `isPrefixOf` with the same signature and behaviour.